# How to correctly extract columns from pdf that are not separated by lines using pdfplumber[Solved]

Tags: python, pdfplumber

I have a pdf file that contains a table of information I need to parse using python. Pdfplumber seems to be the best option for this. However, I ran into a few problems. First of all, the pdf contains a clear table, as in there are separated columns, but these columns aren't separated by line. This means I have to adjust a few settings in the table_settings in pdfplumber. However, I can't seem to get it right. I have the following code:

```py
pdf_file = pdfplumber.open(path_in)
for page in pdf_file.pages:
   tables = page.extract_tables({
     "vertical_strategy": "text",
     "horizontal_strategy": "text",
   })
   for table in tables:
     print("table = ", table)
```

However, the lines don't get split correctly. For example when I have the following row:

```
abcdefghijklmn     2023-07-16
```

it extracts:

```
['abcdefghij', 'klmn', '2023-07-16']
```

How do I change the settings that it will always get the length of the columns right?

Comment: Your observation happens, when there are sufficiently many text pieces that establish a vertical column border. The default for this quantity is 3. Setting this to some higher value may help: "min_words_vertical":10 or something like that.

Comment: @JorjMcKie, thanks, it is almost working. It fixed the main problem I had, but it creates another problem. I have the following 2 tables:
```
table 1
name    date   var1     var2    var3   var4
abcde   2023  a                               b

table2
name    date   var1     var2    var3   var4
abcde   2023  a          b          c        d
```
This results for some reason in two different lists:
`
table1
['name','date', 'var1', 'var2var3var4']
['abcde','2023', 'a', 'b']

table2
['name','date', 'var1', 'var2','var3','var4']
['abcde','2023', 'a', 'b','c','d']
`

Comment: without the page itself this is not solvable I'm afraid. No table detection is a silver bullet. You may need to supply direct help by supplying a list of valid vertical coordinates. Try PyMuPDF, which uses the same detection algorithm, but has superior and fast text extractions that can help with this.

Comment: Specifying own verticals could be done be taking the ones delivered in the first go. Take each left / right column border and check if it cuts a word in pieces. If yes, drop it from the list. Supply the remaining borders as a list of explicit verticals for a second execution of method `find_tables`: "explicit_vertical_lines": [...],